# A SQLiteConnection object for database was leaked

Tags: android, android-database

I am beginner to android program getting below error, tried solution provided like clearing Google play store data on Emulator still getting same error, not using any database connection code but getting database was leaked, any help would be appreciated.

```
Error

03-25 17:16:41.664 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:16:41.669 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:16:41.671 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:20:42.080 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:20:42.082 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:20:42.376 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.


Activity A.java
package com.lifecycle.activity.demo.activity_lifecycle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        Log.i("Activity A","onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("Activity A","onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("Activity A","onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("Activity A","onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("Activity A","onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("Activity A","onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i("Activity A","onRestart");
    }
}

ActivityB.java
package com.lifecycle.activity.demo.activity_lifecycle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by karthicklove on 25/03/17.
 */

public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
        Log.i("Activity B","onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("Activity B","onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("Activity B","onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("Activity B","onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("Activity B","onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("Activity B","onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i("Activity B","onRestart");
    }
}

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lifecycle.activity.demo.activity_lifecycle.ActivityA">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_name1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="134dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="216dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="134dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
activity_b.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/activity_b" />
</LinearLayout>

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lifecycle.activity.demo.activity_lifecycle">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityA">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityB"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? You should learn how to filter the logcat to only show messages from your app.

Comment: Thanks for the information, issue resolved with deleting filter .......

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are observing is not coming from your app but the GMS service:

```
03-25 17:16:41.664 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:16:41.669 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:16:41.671 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:20:42.080 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:20:42.082 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-25 17:20:42.376 2335-2344/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

If it where from you application the package shown will be

```
com.lifecycle.activity.demo.activity_lifecycle
```

Comment: Or more specifically, it would be `com.lifecycle.activity.demo.activity_lifecycle`.